# Failed to instantiate module moment-picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-moment

I'm new in angular so i have a many questions

For Ionic v1 I installed angular-moment-picker
`bower install moment-picker --save`,
there is a directory `bower_components` with `angular-moment-picker`,
I added '`moment-picker'` in `angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ionic-material', 'ui.router', 'moment-picker'])`
RESULT: 
[image: capture d ecran 2017-05-05 a 19 26 14]

What am I doing wrong? Why I have a errors?
Thank you all

Comment: have you referenced "angular-moment-picker.min.js" from your bower_components directory in your index.html? try to keep it after _angular.js_ and before _app.js_(in which `angular.module('starter',[....])` is written ) in your HTML file.

Comment: I solved the problem. Set up .bowerrc `{
  "directory": "www/lib"
}`, installed `bower install moment-picker --save` and added `lib/angular-moment-picker/dist/angular-moment-picker.js` in index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. 
Set up .bowerrc `{
  "directory": "www/lib"
}`, installed `bower install moment-picker --save` and added `lib/angular-moment-picker/dist/angular-moment-picker.js` in index.html